# listview.getChildAt(i) returning NULL

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with very large number of elements and i have set the middle element in the middle of the screen (mRootLayoutHeight is height of the screen)

```
 listview.setSelectionFromTop(adapter.getCount()/2,mRootLayoutHeight/2);
```

But when i try to access all the visible elements of listview on screen using

```
for(int i=listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();i<=listview.getLastVisiblePosition();i++)

       View v=listview.getChildAt(i);
```

View v is always NULL. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getFirstVisiblePosition`, as [per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) returns:

> Returns the position **within the adapter's data set** for the first item displayed on screen.

So, if you have 100 items in your data set, and you scroll down the list, you might be looking at items 15-23. So you'd be iterating over `i=15` to `i=23`.

The `getChildAt` method is from the base `ViewGroup` class however, and returns items at that index on screen - so if you have 8 items on screen (as per the example above), you'll only be able to get items from index 0 - 8, even though those items exist at a different position within the dataset.

So in the example I've supplied here, if you attempted to get the view at index 15, you'd get null, since there are only 8 views in the ListView view group.